# How to create an order in Shopware6 via API?

Tags: shopware

I am trying to create an order in Shopware6 via the Admin API

My Json Object:

```
// POST https://myserver.example.com/api/v3/order

{
    "currencyId": "b7d2554b0ce847cd82f3ac9bd1c0dfca",
    "salesChannelId": "ed47859020cc46349ed5f024c65d09e5",
    "billingAddressId": "629002cceec64dd888b4c52b782d6427",
    "stateId": "9c22101c81d14eb9be55a93a3ba39aa2",
    "languageId": "2fbb5fe2e29a4d70aa5854ce7ce3e20b",
    "currencyFactor": 1,
    "orderCustomer": {
        "email": "abc@xyz.com",
        "salutationId": "1354f03b5d7c414e8b5aaddd0a32e8ca",
        "firstName": "Donald",
        "lastName": "Duck",
        "customerNumber": "10045",
        "customerId": "9432a62c65ae4bcbb335c3bc853d79e8",
        "remoteAddress": "10.147.19.0"
    },
    "price": {
        "netPrice": 33.57,
        "totalPrice": 39.95,
        "calculatedTaxes": [{
            "tax": 6.38,
            "taxRate": 19,
            "price": 39.95
        }],
        "taxRules": [{
            "taxRate": 19,
            "percentage": 100
        }],
        "positionPrice": 39.95,
        "taxStatus": "gross"
    },
    "orderDateTime": "2021-04-21T14:27:57.006+0000",
    "createdAt": "2021-04-21T14:27:57.056+0000",
    "lineItems": [{
        "identifier": "8c380f63883449adec1ee4ccb456c489",
        "quantity": 1,
        "label": "Handtasche - Designer Bag",
        "type": "product",
        "good": true,
        "removable": true,
        "stackable": true,
        "position": 1,
        "price": {
            "unitPrice": 39.95,
            "quantity": 1,
            "totalPrice": 39.95,
            "calculatedTaxes": [{
                "tax": 6.38,
                "taxRate": 19,
                "price": 39.95
            }],
            "taxRules": [{
                "taxRate": 19,
                "percentage": 100
            }]
        },
        "createdAt": "2021-04-21T14:27:57.054+0000"
    }]
}
```

But this gives me the Response:

```
{
"errors": [{
    "code": "0",
    "status": "500",
    "title": "Internal Server Error",
    "detail": "Notice: Trying to access array offset on value of type null",
    "meta": {
        "trace": [{
            "file": "\/data\/srv\/myserver.example.com\/www\/releases\/0.0\/vendor\/shopware\/core\/Framework\/DataAbstractionLayer\/Dbal\/EntityHydrator.php",
            "line": 213,
            "function": "decode",
            "class": "Shopware\\Core\\Framework\\DataAbstractionLayer\\FieldSerializer\\CalculatedPriceFieldSerializer",
            "type": "-\u003E"
        },
        {
            "file": "\/data\/srv\/myserver.example.com\/www\/releases\/0.0\/vendor\/shopware\/core\/Framework\/DataAbstractionLayer\/Dbal\/EntityHydrator.php",
            "line": 49,
            "function": "hydrateEntity",
            "class": "Shopware\\Core\\Framework\\DataAbstractionLayer\\Dbal\\EntityHydrator",
            "type": "-\u003E"
        },
        {
            "file": "\/data\/srv\/myserver.example.com\/www\/releases\/0.0\/vendor\/shopware\/core\/Framework\/DataAbstractionLayer\/Dbal\/EntityReader.php",
            "line": 126,
            "function": "hydrate",
            "class": "Shopware\\Core\\Framework\\DataAbstractionLayer\\Dbal\\EntityHydrator",
            "type": "-\u003E"
        },
        {
            "file": "\/data\/srv\/myserver.example.com\/www\/releases\/0.0\/vendor\/shopware\/core\/Framework\/DataAbstractionLayer\/Dbal\/EntityReader.php",
            "line": 94,
            "function": "_read",
            "class": "Shopware\\Core\\Framework\\DataAbstractionLayer\\Dbal\\EntityReader",
            "type": "-\u003E"
        },
        {
            "file": "\/data\/srv\/myserver.example.com\/www\/releases\/0.0\/vendor\/shopware\/core\/Framework\/DataAbstractionLayer\/Cache\/CachedEntityReader.php",
            "line": 130,
            "function": "read",
            "class": "Shopware\\Core\\Framework\\DataAbstractionLayer\\Dbal\\EntityReader",
            "type": "-\u003E"
        },
        {
            "file": "\/data\/srv\/myserver.example.com\/www\/releases\/0.0\/vendor\/shopware\/core\/Framework\/DataAbstractionLayer\/Cache\/CachedEntityReader.php",
            "line": 55,
            "function": "loadResultByIds",
            "class": "Shopware\\Core\\Framework\\DataAbstractionLayer\\Cache\\CachedEntityReader",
            "type": "-\u003E"
        },
        {
            "file": "\/data\/srv\/myserver.example.com\/www\/releases\/0.0\/vendor\/shopware\/core\/Profiling\/Entity\/EntityReaderProfiler.php",
            "line": 36,
            "function": "read",
            "class": "Shopware\\Core\\Framework\\DataAbstractionLayer\\Cache\\CachedEntityReader",
            "type": "-\u003E"
        },
        {
            "file": "\/data\/srv\/myserver.example.com\/www\/releases\/0.0\/vendor\/shopware\/core\/Framework\/DataAbstractionLayer\/EntityRepository.php",
            "line": 239,
            "function": "read",
            "class": "Shopware\\Core\\Profiling\\Entity\\EntityReaderProfiler",
            "type": "-\u003E"
        },
        {
            "file": "\/data\/srv\/myserver.example.com\/www\/releases\/0.0\/vendor\/shopware\/core\/Framework\/DataAbstractionLayer\/EntityRepository.php",
            "line": 91,
            "function": "read",
            "class": "Shopware\\Core\\Framework\\DataAbstractionLayer\\EntityRepository",
            "type": "-\u003E"
        },
        {
            "file": "\/data\/srv\/myserver.example.com\/www\/releases\/0.0\/vendor\/shopware\/core\/Checkout\/Customer\/Subscriber\/CustomerMetaFieldSubscriber.php",
            "line": 62,
            "function": "search",
            "class": "Shopware\\Core\\Framework\\DataAbstractionLayer\\EntityRepository",
            "type": "-\u003E"
        },
        {
            "file": "\/data\/srv\/myserver.example.com\/www\/releases\/0.0\/vendor\/symfony\/event-dispatcher\/EventDispatcher.php",
            "line": 304,
            "function": "fillCustomerMetaDataFields",
            "class": "Shopware\\Core\\Checkout\\Customer\\Subscriber\\CustomerMetaFieldSubscriber",
            "type": "-\u003E"
        },
        {
            "file": "\/data\/srv\/myserver.example.com\/www\/releases\/0.0\/vendor\/symfony\/event-dispatcher\/EventDispatcher.php",
            "line": 251,
            "function": "Symfony\\Component\\EventDispatcher\\{closure}",
            "class": "Symfony\\Component\\EventDispatcher\\EventDispatcher",
            "type": "::"
        },
        {
            "file": "\/data\/srv\/myserver.example.com\/www\/releases\/0.0\/vendor\/symfony\/event-dispatcher\/EventDispatcher.php",
            "line": 73,
            "function": "callListeners",
            "class": "Symfony\\Component\\EventDispatcher\\EventDispatcher",
            "type": "-\u003E"
        },
        {
            "file": "\/data\/srv\/myserver.example.com\/www\/releases\/0.0\/vendor\/shopware\/core\/Framework\/Webhook\/WebhookDispatcher.php",
            "line": 88,
            "function": "dispatch",
            "class": "Symfony\\Component\\EventDispatcher\\EventDispatcher",
            "type": "-\u003E"
        },
        {
            "file": "\/data\/srv\/myserver.example.com\/www\/releases\/0.0\/vendor\/shopware\/core\/Framework\/Event\/BusinessEventDispatcher.php",
            "line": 46,
            "function": "dispatch",
            "class": "Shopware\\Core\\Framework\\Webhook\\WebhookDispatcher",
            "type": "-\u003E"
        },
        {
            "file": "\/data\/srv\/myserver.example.com\/www\/releases\/0.0\/vendor\/shopware\/core\/Framework\/Event\/NestedEventDispatcher.php",
            "line": 32,
            "function": "dispatch",
            "class": "Shopware\\Core\\Framework\\Event\\BusinessEventDispatcher",
            "type": "-\u003E"
        },
        {
            "file": "\/data\/srv\/myserver.example.com\/www\/releases\/0.0\/vendor\/shopware\/core\/Framework\/Event\/NestedEventDispatcher.php",
            "line": 28,
            "function": "dispatch",
            "class": "Shopware\\Core\\Framework\\Event\\NestedEventDispatcher",
            "type": "-\u003E"
        },
        {
            "file": "\/data\/srv\/myserver.example.com\/www\/releases\/0.0\/vendor\/symfony\/event-dispatcher\/Debug\/TraceableEventDispatcher.php",
            "line": 168,
            "function": "dispatch",
            "class": "Shopware\\Core\\Framework\\Event\\NestedEventDispatcher",
            "type": "-\u003E"
        },
        {
            "file": "\/data\/srv\/myserver.example.com\/www\/releases\/0.0\/vendor\/shopware\/core\/Framework\/DataAbstractionLayer\/EntityRepository.php",
            "line": 178,
            "function": "dispatch",
            "class": "Symfony\\Component\\EventDispatcher\\Debug\\TraceableEventDispatcher",
            "type": "-\u003E"
        },
        {
            "file": "\/data\/srv\/myserver.example.com\/www\/releases\/0.0\/vendor\/shopware\/core\/Framework\/Api\/Controller\/ApiController.php",
            "line": 916,
            "function": "create",
            "class": "Shopware\\Core\\Framework\\DataAbstractionLayer\\EntityRepository",
            "type": "-\u003E"
        },
        {
            "file": "\/data\/srv\/myserver.example.com\/www\/releases\/0.0\/vendor\/shopware\/core\/Framework\/Context.php",
            "line": 183,
            "function": "Shopware\\Core\\Framework\\Api\\Controller\\{closure}",
            "class": "Shopware\\Core\\Framework\\Api\\Controller\\ApiController",
            "type": "-\u003E"
        },
        {
            "file": "\/data\/srv\/myserver.example.com\/www\/releases\/0.0\/vendor\/shopware\/core\/Framework\/Api\/Controller\/ApiController.php",
            "line": 934,
            "function": "scope",
            "class": "Shopware\\Core\\Framework\\Context",
            "type": "-\u003E"
        },
        {
            "file": "\/data\/srv\/myserver.example.com\/www\/releases\/0.0\/vendor\/shopware\/core\/Framework\/Api\/Controller\/ApiController.php",
            "line": 780,
            "function": "executeWriteOperation",
            "class": "Shopware\\Core\\Framework\\Api\\Controller\\ApiController",
            "type": "-\u003E"
        },
        {
            "file": "\/data\/srv\/myserver.example.com\/www\/releases\/0.0\/vendor\/shopware\/core\/Framework\/Api\/Controller\/ApiController.php",
            "line": 452,
            "function": "write",
            "class": "Shopware\\Core\\Framework\\Api\\Controller\\ApiController",
            "type": "-\u003E"
        },
        {
            "file": "\/data\/srv\/myserver.example.com\/www\/releases\/0.0\/vendor\/symfony\/http-kernel\/HttpKernel.php",
            "line": 158,
            "function": "create",
            "class": "Shopware\\Core\\Framework\\Api\\Controller\\ApiController",
            "type": "-\u003E"
        },
        {
            "file": "\/data\/srv\/myserver.example.com\/www\/releases\/0.0\/vendor\/symfony\/http-kernel\/HttpKernel.php",
            "line": 80,
            "function": "handleRaw",
            "class": "Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\HttpKernel",
            "type": "-\u003E"
        },
        {
            "file": "\/data\/srv\/myserver.example.com\/www\/releases\/0.0\/vendor\/symfony\/http-kernel\/Kernel.php",
            "line": 201,
            "function": "handle",
            "class": "Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\HttpKernel",
            "type": "-\u003E"
        },
        {
            "file": "\/data\/srv\/myserver.example.com\/www\/releases\/0.0\/vendor\/symfony\/http-kernel\/HttpCache\/SubRequestHandler.php",
            "line": 85,
            "function": "handle",
            "class": "Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\Kernel",
            "type": "-\u003E"
        },
        {
            "file": "\/data\/srv\/myserver.example.com\/www\/releases\/0.0\/vendor\/symfony\/http-kernel\/HttpCache\/HttpCache.php",
            "line": 477,
            "function": "handle",
            "class": "Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\HttpCache\\SubRequestHandler",
            "type": "::"
        },
        {
            "file": "\/data\/srv\/myserver.example.com\/www\/releases\/0.0\/vendor\/symfony\/http-kernel\/HttpCache\/HttpCache.php",
            "line": 267,
            "function": "forward",
            "class": "Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\HttpCache\\HttpCache",
            "type": "-\u003E"
        },
        {
            "file": "\/data\/srv\/myserver.example.com\/www\/releases\/0.0\/vendor\/symfony\/http-kernel\/HttpCache\/HttpCache.php",
            "line": 283,
            "function": "pass",
            "class": "Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\HttpCache\\HttpCache",
            "type": "-\u003E"
        },
        {
            "file": "\/data\/srv\/myserver.example.com\/www\/releases\/0.0\/vendor\/symfony\/http-kernel\/HttpCache\/HttpCache.php",
            "line": 211,
            "function": "invalidate",
            "class": "Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\HttpCache\\HttpCache",
            "type": "-\u003E"
        },
        {
            "file": "\/data\/srv\/myserver.example.com\/www\/releases\/0.0\/vendor\/shopware\/core\/HttpKernel.php",
            "line": 163,
            "function": "handle",
            "class": "Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\HttpCache\\HttpCache",
            "type": "-\u003E"
        },
        {
            "file": "\/data\/srv\/myserver.example.com\/www\/releases\/0.0\/vendor\/shopware\/core\/HttpKernel.php",
            "line": 80,
            "function": "doHandle",
            "class": "Shopware\\Core\\HttpKernel",
            "type": "-\u003E"
        },
        {
            "file": "\/data\/srv\/myserver.example.com\/www\/releases\/0.0\/public\/index.php",
            "line": 83,
            "function": "handle",
            "class": "Shopware\\Core\\HttpKernel",
            "type": "-\u003E"
        }],
        "file": "\/data\/srv\/myserver.example.com\/www\/releases\/0.0\/vendor\/shopware\/core\/Framework\/DataAbstractionLayer\/FieldSerializer\/CalculatedPriceFieldSerializer.php",
        "line": 51
    }
}]
```

I tried all kinds of different variations with the "price" object, with calculated taxes, without and anything that came to my mind, no success.

How would a correct JSON object look like that successfully creates an order?

Comment: Are you able to use xdebug and set a breakpoint in the line mentioned to find out which property it tries to access?

Answer (score 0):

When I work with the API, sometimes I just create an entity manually (e.g. Order) & then try to GET it via the API. Then you can just copy the formatting and feed it back to your POST call.

You might be missing `"rawTotal": 468.55` in your main price object.

That said, the error suggests that the value should be an array, but it is not set. They don't use version numbers in their API anymore, so maybe this is no longer relevant :)